# Making a contiguous map of Alaska, British Columbia, and Washington in R

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to create a map of AK, British Columbia, and WA where the states/province are contiguous.  I've tried a couple of things, the most recent shown below.
Thanks!

```
states<-c( 'Washington' , 'Alaska')
province<-c('British Columbia')
us<-getData('GADM' , country = 'USA', level = 1)
canada<-getData('GADM' , country = 'CAN', level = 1)

us.bbox <- bbox(us.states)
ca.bbox <- bbox(ca.provinces)
xlim <- c( min( us.bbox[1,1], ca.bbox[1,1]), max( us.bbox[1,2], ca.bbox[1,2]))
ylim <- c( min( us.bbox[2,1], ca.bbox[2,1]), max( us.bbox[2,2], ca.bbox[2,2]))
plot(us.states, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
plot(ca.provinces, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
```

When I run the above I get a tiny map of AK and a tiny map of WA kind of near each other, but my R crashes before I get BC.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We don't have `us.states` or `ca.provinces`.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply be running out of memory for the plot ( or the margins are too large ) I would recommend writing it to a file like so. I also put in add=T in the second plot so it would be contiguous.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
states<-c('Washington', 'Alaska')
province<-c('British Columbia')
us<-getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
canada<-getData('GADM', country='CAN', level=1)

us.bbox <- bbox(us)
ca.bbox <- bbox(canada)
xlim <- c(min(us.bbox[1,1], ca.bbox[1,1]), max(us.bbox[1,2], ca.bbox[1,2]))
ylim <- c(min(us.bbox[2,1], ca.bbox[2,1]), max(us.bbox[2,2], ca.bbox[2,2]))
pdf("F:/plot.pdf")
plot(us, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plot(canada, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim,add=T)
dev.off()
```

As @hrbrmstr noted we do not have the us.states or ca.provinces, so I did this for the entire continent, the same would apply for a subset of the information.

> This is what you were initially looking for.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
states<-c('Washington', 'Alaska')
province<-c('British Columbia')
us<-getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
canada<-getData('GADM', country='CAN', level=1)

us.states <- us[which(us$NAME_1 %in% states),]
ca.provinces <- canada[which(canada$NAME_1 %in% province),] 

us.bbox <- bbox(us.states)
ca.bbox <- bbox(ca.provinces)
xlim <- c(min(us.bbox[1,1], ca.bbox[1,1]), max(us.bbox[1,2], ca.bbox[1,2]))
ylim <- c(min(us.bbox[2,1], ca.bbox[2,1]), max(us.bbox[2,2], ca.bbox[2,2]))
pdf("F:/plot.pdf")
plot(us.states, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plot(ca.provinces, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim,add=T)
dev.off()
```

Comment: OP cld also run `rgeos::gSimplify` on the maps (running it and `gBuffer` would both be good since the UC Davis detailed maps cld do with a bit of data cleaning anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation

```
library(raster)

us<-getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
canada<-getData('GADM', country='CAN', level=1)

us.states <- us[us$NAME_1 %in% c('Washington', 'Alaska'),]
ca.provinces <- canada[canada$NAME_1 == 'British Columbia',] 

usca <- bind(us.states, ca.provinces)
plot(usca)
```

An issue with this is that there are parts of Alaska in the eastern hemisphere. You could cut that off, but either way you should use an appropriate coordinate reference system (map projection), and that will make this go away. Perhaps something like this

```
crs <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-130  +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
x <- spTransform(usca, CRS(crs))
plot(x)
```